# How to change _escaped_fragment_ by #! in wordpress

Tags: ajax, wordpress, .htaccess

I work on wordpress and ajax. After activating the "Really Simple SSL" plugin, the text 'https' is displayed just before _escaped_fragment_ and generates a 404 error.

> RedirectMatch permanent
>   https:// www.site.com/parent/item/https?_escaped_fragment_=mg_ld_4040
>   to https:// www.site.com/parent/item/

I have already tried to redirect it to the right page and added :

> < meta name="fragment" content="!">

but _escaped_fragment_ always remains on the url.
Is there a good, clean and acceptable way to redirect users to the correct URL and replace _escaped_fragment_ with #! ?

Answer (score 0):

Why does your URL contains the sequence `#!`? Can you change it? Because ajax content is not crawlable, the sequence is part of the (Google) specification to make this content crawlable, and most of the internet big fishes are using it by now.

How does it works? Lets say you have a url like `www.example.com/folder#!id=4`. It means some content of the url is delivered by ajax, and it depends of the information id=4, called hash. The Google crawler will try to read the page `www.example.com/folder?_escaped_fragment_=id=4` instead, where, according to the specification, the crawler expects to find a no ajax version of the same page.

I don't like it at all, but it works, and that is why Twitter, Facebook, Groveshark and a lot of other big fishes are using the specification. So when you share a grooveshark song in the facebook (a 100% ajax page), facebook knows where to find the non ajax version of the same page. But because of that Facebook is also trying to change your urls.

Comment: Thanks for you response!
After some research on Google, I see that **#!** is automatically replaced by **_escaped_fragment_** by Google.
But now, the biggest problem is that after the activation of plugin "Really simple plugin", the https sequence appears in the middle of the url like : 
`www.example.com/folder/https?_escaped_fragment_=id=4`